# Is it possible to run xserver without any window?

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server

I run a second xserver through tty2 this way:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
xinit -- :1
```

I don't have any .xinitrc file defined and I get only a black screen with xterm window. It looks like that running xterm is hardcoded in xinit bin. Is it possible to run xserver without that xterm window ? When I close xterm the screen is redirected back to tty2 and there is a messasge:

> xinit: connection to xserver lost

Does it mean that xserver can't be run without any "regular" window ? (there is always also a root window)

Comment: How do you run your first X server? A display manager (gdm, kdm, xdm)? Why don't you configure the display manager to run the second server in the same way it runs the first server?

Comment: I use UBuntu 16.04 LTS , so there is lightdm. I play with a minimal X11 setup just for learning purpose.

Comment: Just start `X :1` without xinit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual page is the place to start.  From ["man xinit"](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.7.0/doc/xinit.1.html):

> If no specific client program is given on the command line, **`xinit`** will look for a file in the user's home directory called **`.xinitrc`** to run as a shell script to start up client programs. If no such file exists, **`xinit`** will use the following as a default:
>
> ```
>     xterm -geometry +1+1 -n login -display :0
> ```

The X server will wait until that program stops before shutting down. You can certainly use different programs, including those that do not open a window.  But without a terminal (or window manager) the X display will be hard to use.

Further reading: [**`startx`**](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/startx.1.html) manual page.

Comment: So when using xinit I can't close xterm and still have xserver running, right ?  (I know that such setup doesn't make much sense but I want to check all options. I can later open xterm again remotely, for example through ssh). startx internally also uses xinit, what are other posiblities to run xserver ?

Comment: The X server expects to have a client program running, which could be xterm or some other application.  Usually the "other" application is a window manager.  Once there are no clients, X stops :-)